# Unexpected $markerCount (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php

Not sure what I'm missing here....     The error I get is... 
   **Parse error**:  syntax error, unexpected '$markerCount' (T_VARIABLE) in **updateMarkerLocations.php** on line **8**

Apparently $markerCount is unexpected? Below is the entire code I have.
Thanks!

```
<?php
include 'db_const.php';

function insertMarkerLocations()
{
$markerCount = 0;
if (isset($_POST['markerCount'])
    $markerCount = $_POST['markerCount']);

$con = mysql_connect($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS );
if (!con) {
    $msg = 'Could not connect to DB to save';
    return $msg;
}
mysql_select_db($DB_NAME, $con);

$ID = $_POST['ID'];

for($i=0 ; $i < $markerCount; $i++){ 
      $index = $i;
      ++$index;
      $curMarkerID = $_POST["markerID$index"];
      $curLang = $_POST["lang$index"];
      $curLat = $_POST["lat$index"];
  // Now write the current marker details in to the db.
  $query = INSERT INTO userinfo (ID, markerID, lang, lat ) VALUES ('$ID', '$curMarkerID', '$curLang', '$curLat');
  mysql_query($query)
    or die(mysql_error());
}
$msg = "SUCCESS";
return $msg;
}

$msg = insertMarkerLocations();
echo json_encode($msg);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
if (isset($_POST['markerCount'])
    $markerCount = $_POST['markerCount']);
```

should be

```
if (isset($_POST['markerCount']))
    $markerCount = $_POST['markerCount'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an unwanted paranthesis at the end of

```
$markerCount = $_POST['markerCount']);
```

Remove it and replace with the following:

```
$markerCount = $_POST['markerCount'];
```